# Pocket-sized Android phone with big battery and good camera

Tags: android, smartphones

I need an Android phone for long bicycle trips.

Requirements in order of importance:

1. Long battery lifetime (at least 12 hours with frequent GPS & camera usage, the longer the better)
2. Small enough to fit in trousers pocket
3. Rather good GPS
4. Rather robust, as it might fall a few times
5. Rather good camera (mostly daytime landscapes)
6. Price: Hopefully less than 500 EUR

Comment: batteries and cameras tend to work in inverse size and quality typically.